# MongoDB C# driver does not recognize some types

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying MongoDB for the first time with the official C# driver. In the screenshot below you can see that the dependencies are installed (newest version 2.1.0-rc1, via NuGet). But for some reason VS does not recognize the types `MongoDatabase` and `MongoCollection<T>` (These should exist, following a tutorial) - only the interfaces. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What does the Error List say, did you try compile anyway, maybe intellisense has gave up.

Comment: Sorry for German: "Fehler1: Der Typ- oder Namespacename 'MongoDatabase' konnte nicht gefunden werden. (Fehlt eine Using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis?)"

Comment: Just sais that the type or namespace `MongoDatabase` could not be found, same for `MongoCollection<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use obsolete types. If you really need to use it then you should load [legacy driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver). But better solution is to use [new style](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/)

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the case. Very surprising - since the tutorial was from June 2014 - that there was a breaking change.